# Order of element gets changed when it's focused in Grid layout

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have placed some elements in a grid without any Row & Column definitions.

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Text="{Binding ButtonText}" CornerRadius="5" />
    <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding IconImageSource}" InputTransparent="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Here, the image is the top element. When the button got tapped, the image goes to back. Why is this happening and is there any way to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

This reason is from **[Fast Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/fast-renderers#backwards-compatibility)** .

Fast renderers are available for the following controls in Xamarin.Forms on Android:

- Button
- Image
- Label
- Frame

Functionally, these fast renderers are no different to the legacy renderers. From **Xamarin.Forms 4.0** onwards, all applications targeting `FormsAppCompatActivity` will use these fast renderers by default.

Fast renderers can be overridden with the following approaches:

1. Enabling the legacy renderers by adding the following line of code to your `MainActivity` class before calling `Forms.Init`:

   `Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");`
2. Using custom renderers that target the legacy renderers. Any existing custom renderers will continue to function with the legacy renderers.
3. Specifying a different `View.Visual`, such as `Material`, that uses different renderers. For more information about Material Visual, see [Xamarin.Forms Material Visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual).

So , here **Solution** is adding the following to your MainActivity.OnCreate before the `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState)` call:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers"); //add code here

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
    LoadApplication (new App ()); // method is new in 1.3
}
```

The effect :

[image]